# Something like \includeonly but for \includepdf?

Tags: pdfpages, include

Let's suppose we have a document like the one below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\include{Text_A}
\include{Text_B}
\include{Text_C}
\include{Text_D}
\includepdf{Attachment_A}
\includepdf{Attachment_B}
\includepdf{Attachment_C}
\end{document}
```

I can use the `\includeonly` command to only compile certain parts.
So if I only want `Text_A` and `Text_C`, I can add `\includeonly{Text_A,Text_C}` to the preamble. 
Now my problem is that this only works for parts which are included with `\include`.

I'm looking for a way to combine this with parts that are included with `\includepdf`. So if I only want `Text_A`, `Attachment_A` and `Attachment_C`, I have to comment out the lines one by one. This is rather unpleasant if there are a lot of files included via `\includepdf` and if the command contains multiple lines of options.

I could do some refactoring and put the `\includepdf` commands into single files so that I'm able to use `\include` exclusively in the main document. But I wonder if there might be a more elegant solution?

Comment: The primary function of \includeonly is to keep track of page numbers and aux files.  Of course, you could create a bunch of .tex files consisting of one \includepdf command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can borrow the `\includeonly` test used by `\include`.

This just includes the text and attachment for B

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\let\oldincludepdf\includepdf
\newcommand\zzincludepdf[2][]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#2}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \IfFileExists{#2.pdf}{\oldincludepdf[#1]{#2}}{\typeout{no file #2.pdf}}%
  \fi}
\let\includepdf\zzincludepdf
\makeatother

\includeonly{Text_B,Attachment_B}
\begin{document}
\include{Text_A}
\include{Text_B}
\include{Text_C}
\include{Text_D}
\includepdf{Attachment_A}
\includepdf[pages=-]{Attachment_B}
\includepdf{Attachment_C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you seem to know something about the inner working ;-)

Comment: Wow, thank you. You really have some deep knowledge! But this will only work as long as there are no options for `\includepdf`, right? When I add `\includepdf[pages=-]{Attachment_B}` or similar compilation fails :(

Comment: @schmattes ohh details... give me a minute and I'll put the optional argument back

Comment: @schmattes try now

Comment: Works as advertised :) Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again @David but I've noticed that it does not work if the linked pdf is located in a subfolder like `\includepdf{folder/Attachment_A}`. That's not so important, but I just want to point it out in case anyone should wonder.

Comment: @schmattes it should work if used `folder/Attachment_A` in `\includeonly` I think?

Comment: Oh, you're right. My fault.